# Error: definition of ‘int __atomic_compare_exchange(params1)’ ambiguates built-in declaration ‘bool __atomic_compare_exchange(params2)’

Tags: c

I am trying to build Berkley Db 4.8.30 on Ubuntu 20.0.4 LTS

This is what I did so far:

```
wget http://download.oracle.com/berkeley-db/db-4.8.30.zip
unzip db-4.8.30.zip
cd db-4.8.30
cd build_unix/
../dist/configure --prefix=/usr/local --enable-cxx
make
make install
```

During the compilation, I get the error messsage:

> error: definition of ‘int __atomic_compare_exchange(db_atomic_t*,
> atomic_value_t, atomic_value_t)’ ambiguates built-in declaration ‘bool
> __atomic_compare_exchange(long unsigned int, volatile void*, void*, void*, int, int)’

The compilation flags are set correctly for my platform. Here are the relevant section of code:

### atomic.h (truncated)

```
#if defined(DB_WIN32)
typedef DWORD   atomic_value_t;
#else
typedef int32_t  atomic_value_t;
#endif
/*
 * Windows CE has strange issues using the Interlocked APIs with variables
 * stored in shared memory. It seems like the page needs to have been written
 * prior to the API working as expected. Work around this by allocating an
 * additional 32-bit value that can be harmlessly written for each value
 * used in Interlocked instructions.
 */
#if defined(DB_WINCE)
typedef struct {
    volatile atomic_value_t value;
    volatile atomic_value_t dummy;
} db_atomic_t;
#else
typedef struct {
    volatile atomic_value_t value;
} db_atomic_t;
#endif


#define atomic_compare_exchange(env, p, o, n)   \
    __atomic_compare_exchange((p), (o), (n))



/*
 * x86/gcc Compare exchange for shared latches. i486+
 *  Returns 1 for success, 0 for failure
 *
 * GCC 4.1+ has an equivalent  __sync_bool_compare_and_swap() as well as
 * __sync_val_compare_and_swap() which returns the value read from *dest
 * http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.0/gcc/Atomic-Builtins.html
 * which configure could be changed to use.
 */
static inline int __atomic_compare_exchange(
    db_atomic_t *p, atomic_value_t oldval, atomic_value_t newval)
{
    atomic_value_t was;

    if (p->value != oldval) /* check without expensive cache line locking */
        return 0;
    __asm__ __volatile__("lock; cmpxchgl %1, (%2);"
        :"=a"(was)
        :"r"(newval), "r"(p), "a"(oldval)
        :"memory", "cc");
    return (was == oldval);
}
```

I think I need to set a pragma to ignore the type safety check ... but not too sure. How do I resolve this compilation error?

Comment: This would be better posted to a support channel for the product you are trying to build.  Editing your compiler's headers is definitely not the way to go

Comment: It seems like the Berkeley DB authors unwisely chose to define a function whose name starts `__`, which is a reserved identifier.  In the meantime, GCC, as it is entitled to do, decided to define a different and incompatible function with the same name.  I think you either have to rename all instances, or else port it to use GCC's function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function

```
bool __atomic_compare_exchange(long unsigned int, volatile void*, void*, void*, int, int)
```

is a built-in GCC compiler function for an atomic operation. See here for details:
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html

The function

```
int __atomic_compare_exchange(db_atomic_t*, atomic_value_t, atomic_value_t)
```

seems to be a function of Berkley Db 4.8.30 and this creates a conflict. No two functions may have the same name.

The following link is a link to a patch (including patch instructions) that you can apply to solve the problem:
https://gist.github.com/danieldk/5700533

Comment: As noted in the comments to the question, this is a problem with Berkely DB:  [`__atomic_compare_exchange` is a reserved identifier](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.3)

Comment: @AndrewHenle I know, why else would I have posted a link for a patch to Berkley DB that solves the issue?